# Tracking deployed application's files

Tags: git, deployment, rpm

What do you guys use to deploy and application and track their files in production? I mean tracking if the file was not changed directly in the server?

thanks

Comment: Do you need to find out if files have been changed in production or where a given set of files came from originally?

Comment: I need to know if some file had been changed outside the formal deploy process. Ex.: If using RPM to deploy software is possible to check if the deployed files was changed after RPM was installed.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Git for 3 years to track /usr/local on a HPC production cluster.

For 2.2G (mostly binaries) it takes 1 minute running `git log -n 1; git status` (over NFS!) to convince myself that the files were not modified after deployment. On local disk the scan would take seconds. If change did happen, I see which files and diffs (if it's not binary).

Comment: +1. I didn't see Git as a valid solution at the time, but you can see alternatives discussed at http://serverfault.com/questions/3852/what-tool-do-you-recommend-to-track-changes-on-a-linux-unix-server, and one of the top solution (etckeeper http://joey.kitenet.net/code/etckeeper/) is based on a dvcs. So as long as you don't abuse it (for deployment for instance), it seems a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I **wouldn't** track those files through a VCS on the server.
Normally (except for simple webapp deployment), you don't have any "unnecessary" tool on a production server past the ones you actually need to run the app (i.e.: certainly not a VCS).

A Version Control System is there up until the pre-production environment, for you to get a specific tag to deploy.
But once that tag is used to get your files, then a deployment process takes place:

- replace the variables from your generic config files with production-specific values
- stop the production processes
- copy and deploy the files onto the production server
- restart
- monitor...

So I would set an external (i.e. not directly managed by a VCS) job to compare a versioned file and the corresponding deployed file.

Comment: What about deploying binaries (WAR, EAR, native)?

Comment: @HGF: those files are not in the VCS anyway, and are produced/deployed through a release and deployment management process. A system which would monitor their integrity (i.e. "have they been changed on the server?") would likely compare the SHA1/MD5 key of those files between the ones published on the server and an artifact repository like Nexus, where said binaries can be stored and referenced (with a SHA1/MD5 key automatically generated upon storage).