# Github download folder as zip

Tags: github, download, repository, zip

How can I provide visitors of my Github repositories a link to download the builds folder of my repository as zip file? The folder contains a executable, shaders and textures needed by the application.

Of course I could manually build a zip file of that directory and add that to the repository. But that results in redundant files, bigger size and unnecessary work *for each commit*.

So is there a way to zip and download a specific folder and its content of a git repository on Github? Maybe Github has the ability already?

Comment: Note: since July 2013, you can attached binaries to a GitHub release. See [my updated answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14293882/6309).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update July 2013:

As I mention in "[Releasing a build artifact on github](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5207352/6309)", you can define a release and **upload** binaries attached to that release!

[image: GitHub release]

---

Original answer (January 2013)

No, you cannot do it with GitHub alone.

And GitHub recently got rid of its [upload feature](https://github.com/blog/1302-goodbye-uploads), which would have allowed you to uplad a binary for your user to get (without making your git repo grow in size).

So you need to store said binary in another external (binary) repository ([Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), or [Amazon s3 service](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/), or...)

Answer (score 1):

Provided you rely on a public Continuous Integration server, you may also promote the result of your build as downloadable artifacts.

For instance, JetBrains TeamCity provides such feature and Codebetter.com generously provides a free **[TeamCity server for .Net/Mono](http://codebetter.com/codebetter-ci/)** open source projects.

[image: Imgur]

Comment: A good alternative storage location for those binaries (which I missed in my answer). +1