# How to release versions on GitHub through the command line?

Tags: api, version-control, github, automation, release

GitHub has a [feature](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software) on their website that allows you to mark particular snapshots of your repository as release versions of software. Sample URL: https://github.com/github/orchestrator/releases

Is there a way I can do this from the command line, without having to log on and use the interface?  I realize the feature is not a part of git, but I was hoping there is some kind of api or solution other people use to make the process automated.

Comment: I find the easier option these days is to use [hub](http://github.com/github/hub)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to release a build artifact on GitHub with a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207269/how-to-release-a-build-artifact-on-github-with-a-script)

Answer (score 13):

There are many projects offering this — the order below is just for the sake indexing things —:

1. cheton's [github-release-cli](https://github.com/cheton/github-release-cli) in Node (JS)
2. c4milo's [github-release](https://github.com/c4milo/github-release) in Go (aims simplicity)
3. aktau's [github-release](https://github.com/aktau/github-release) in Go

And you can even do this directly with `curl` directly:

```sh
OWNER=
REPOSITORY=
ACCESS_TOKEN=
VERSION=
curl --data '{"tag_name": "v$VERSION",
                "target_commitish": "master",
                "name": "v$VERSION",
                "body": "Release of version $VERSION",
                "draft": false,
                "prerelease": false}' \
    https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPOSITORY/releases?access_token=$ACCESS_TOKEN
```

from Barry Kooij's [Create Github releases via command line](https://www.barrykooij.com/create-github-releases-via-command-line/).

If you want a full featured answer on StackOverflow: [Releasing a build artifact on Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207269/releasing-a-build-artifact-on-github).

Comment: I would recommend users to use `hub` instead, since the tool is also in Go, but officially maintained by GitHub: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52353299/895245

Answer (score 11):

It can be done using github cli

`gh release create <tagname> --target <branchname>`

[Github CLI](https://cli.github.com/)

If you get a 400 error, check your branch name for typos

Comment: Thanks for it! It works great! I made an alias for myself btw to make this even faster, also because I always use `main` for releases. This is what I have:
`alias create-release='function _create_release() { gh release create $1 --target main; }; _create_release'`

Answer (score 5):

You could use the ["Create release" API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#create-a-release) of the [GitHub V3 API](http://developer.github.com/v3/).

```
POST /repos/:owner/:repo/releases
```

See for instance this ruby script "[`create-release.rb`](https://gist.github.com/mlafeldt/6716465)" by [Mathias Lafeldt (`mlafeldt`)](https://github.com/mlafeldt):

```ruby
require "net/https"
require "json"

gh_token     = ENV.fetch("GITHUB_TOKEN")
gh_user      = ARGV.fetch(0)
gh_repo      = ARGV.fetch(1)
release_name = ARGV.fetch(2)
release_desc = ARGV[3]

uri = URI("https://api.github.com")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/repos/#{gh_user}/#{gh_repo}/releases")
request["Accept"] = "application/vnd.github.manifold-preview"
request["Authorization"] = "token #{gh_token}"
request.body = {
  "tag_name"         => release_name,
  "target_commitish" => "master",
  "name"             => release_name,
  "body"             => release_desc,
  "draft"            => false,
  "prerelease"       => false,
}.to_json

response = http.request(request)
abort response.body unless response.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)

release = JSON.parse(response.body)
puts release
```

Comment: here's a python version that also uploads a file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153418/can-someone-give-a-python-requests-example-of-uploading-a-release-asset-in-githu/52354681#52354681

Answer (score 4):

**`hub` official Go-based GitHub CLI tool**

https://github.com/github/hub

An Ubuntu package as added as of 19.04: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=hub | https://github.com/github/hub/issues/718

```
sudo apt install hub
```

Otherwise, for older Ubuntu, first install Go. On Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/959932/installation-instructions-for-golang-1-9-into-ubuntu-16-04/1075726#1075726

Then install `hub`:

```
go get github.com/github/hub
```

Once `hub` is installed, from inside your repo:

```
hub release create -a prebuilt.zip -m 'release title' tag-name
```

This:

- prompts for your password the first time, and then automatically creates and stores an API token locally
- creates a non annotated tag on the remote called `tag-name`
- creates a release associated to that tag
- uploads `prebuilt.zip` as an attachment

You can also provide your existing API token with the `GITHUB_TOKEN` environment variable.

For other `release` operations, see:

```
hub release --help
```

Tested on `hub` [de684cb613c47572cc9ec90d4fd73eef80aef09c](https://github.com/github/hub/tree/de684cb613c47572cc9ec90d4fd73eef80aef09c).

**Python example without any dependencies**

If you are like me and don't want to install yet another language:

[Can someone give a python requests example of uploading a release asset in github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153418/can-someone-give-a-python-requests-example-of-uploading-a-release-asset-in-githu/52354681#52354681)

Comment: You can get hub precompiled from many package managers, no need to install go :) But thanks for the post

Comment: @TheUnfunCat hi, thanks for pinging me, a package was juts made available for 19.04, so I updated the answer. Still, when something is available from the "per-language-package" manager, I tend to use that one ;-)

Answer (score 1):

you can do that using the **[GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_release_create)**

> *To create a release from an annotated git tag, first create one*
> *locally with git, push the tag to GitHub, then run this command.*

`gh release create <tag> [<files>...] --target <branchname>`

**Options**

> -d, --draft             Save the release as a draft instead of publishing it
>
> -n, --notes string      Release notes
>
> -F, --notes-file file   Read release notes from file
>
> -p, --prerelease        Mark the release as a prerelease
>
> , --target branch     Target branch or full commit SHA (default:
> main branch)
>
> -t, --title string      Release title

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have checked out the right branch from the github repo (origin) and it is in synced with it, to e.g. automagically create a version 2.5.0 release, do:

```
git tag -a -m 'your comment' v2.5.0
git push origin v2.5.0
```

Comment: this creates a tag, not a release

Comment: Of course this creates a tag and until Microsoft took over, pushing it to github actually caused the creation of a release. You obviously missed the '-a' option.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag
-a creates an ANNOTATED TAG which is not the same as a release

Comment: Creating an annotated tag with a proper version string and pushing it to github caused github to create a release.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a simple curl command:

```
curl -X POST -u YOURGITUSERNAME:YOURTOKEN --data '{"tag_name": "YOURTAGNAME","target_commitish": "YOURREPO","name": "YOURTAGNAME","body": "YOUR TAG DESCRIPTION","draft": false,"prerelease": false}' https://api.github.com/repos/YOURGITSITE/YOURREPO/releases
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$version = 'v1.0.0'
$data='{"tag_name": "${version}", "target_commitish": "master", "name": "${version}", "body": "Release of version ${version}", "draft": false, "prerelease": false}'
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: token $(git_token)" -d $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($data) https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPOSITORY/releases
```

I was using Powershell in azure DevOps. `git_token` is a variable defined in my build pipeline.
Hope it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

When using [`gh release create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_release_create), make sure to use the new `--verify-tag` option with [`gh` 2.21.0 (Dec. 2022)](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.21.0), from [PR 6632](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/6632) which fixes [issue 6566](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/6566):

> When running `gh release create <tag> --verify-tag`, we query among repository tags via the GitHub API before creating the release, and abort the command if the tag was not found.

Error message:

```
tag %s doesn't exist in the repo %s, aborting due to --verify-tag flag
```