# Can someone give a python requests example of uploading a release asset in github?

Tags: python, github, github-api

```
url = 'https://github.abc.defcom/api/v3/repos/abc/def/releases/401/assets?name=foo.sh'
r = requests.post(url, headers={'Content-Type':'application/binary'}, data=open('sometext.txt','r'), auth=('user','password'))
```

This is giving me

```
>>> r.text
u'{"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.4/v3"}'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: could be a url error, also could be an auth error according to that docs link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I'll preface this with the advice that if you use a library it's as easy as:

```
from github3 import GitHubEnterprise

gh = GitHubEnterprise(token=my_token)
repository = gh.repository('abc', 'def')
release = repository.release(id=401)
asset = release.upload_asset(content_type='application/binary', name='foo.sh', asset=open('sometext.txt', 'rb'))
```

With that in mind, I'll also preface this with "application/binary" is not a real media type (see: https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)

Next, if you [read the documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#upload-a-release-asset), you'll notice that GitHub requires clients that have *real* SNI (Server Name Indication), so depending on your version of Python, you may also have to install `pyOpenSSL`, `pyasn1`, and `ndg-httpsclient` from PyPI.

I'm not sure what the URL looks like for enterprise instances, but for public GitHub, it looks like:

```
https://uploads.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases/1/assets?name=foo.sh
```

So you're going to have that as `url`, plus you're going to want your auth credentials (in your case you seem to want to use basic auth). Then you're going to want a *valid* media-type in the headers, e.g.,

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
```

And your call would look pretty much exactly correct:

```
requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=open('file.txt', 'rb'), auth=(username, password))
```

To get the correct url, you should do:

```
release = requests.get(release_url, auth=(username, password))
upload_url = release.json().get('upload_url')
```

**Note** this is a URITemplate. You'll need to remove the templating or use a library like `uritemplate.py` to parse it and use it to build your URL for you.

One last reminder, github3.py (the library in the original example) takes care of all of this for you.

Answer (score 3):

**APIv3 upload example without any external dependencies**

Usage:

```
GITHUB_TOKEN=<token> ./create-release username/reponame <tag-name> <path-to-upload>
```

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json
import os
import sys

from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

repo = sys.argv[1]
tag = sys.argv[2]
upload_file = sys.argv[3]

token = os.environ['GITHUB_TOKEN']

url_template = 'https://{}.github.com/repos/' + repo + '/releases'

# Create.
_json = json.loads(urlopen(Request(
    url_template.format('api'),
    json.dumps({
        'tag_name': tag,
        'name': tag,
        'prerelease': True,
    }).encode(),
    headers={
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json',
        'Authorization': 'token ' + token,
    },
)).read().decode())
release_id = _json['id']

# Upload.
with open(upload_file, 'br') as myfile:
    content = myfile.read()
_json = json.loads(urlopen(Request(
    url_template.format('uploads') + '/' + str(release_id) + '/assets?' \
      + urlencode({'name': os.path.split(upload_file)[1]}),
    content,
    headers={
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json',
        'Authorization': 'token ' + token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/zip',
    },
)).read().decode())
```

Superset question with any language: [How to release a build artifact asset on GitHub with a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207269/how-to-release-a-build-artifact-asset-on-github-with-a-script/52354732#52354732)