# upload files to github directory using github api

Tags: github, github-api

I want to upload files from my system to a directory in github repo using the api .Is there any api endpoint which allows me to do that.

Comment: For assets: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207269/how-to-release-a-build-artifact-asset-on-github-with-a-script

Answer (score 8):

You should use the [GitHub CRUD API](https://github.com/blog/1498-file-crud-and-repository-statistics-now-available-in-the-api) which was introduced in .May 2013

It includes:

- [File Create](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file)

  ```
    PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path
  ```
- [File Update](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#update-a-file)

  ```
    PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path
  ```
- [File Delete](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#delete-a-file)

  ```
    DELETE /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path
  ```

Comment: I am successfully able to upload small files, but the API fails with (502 BAD Gateway) response on bigger files( > 10mb). Is there a solution for using this for bigger files?

Comment: I suspect not. You would have to use Git LFS (https://git-lfs.github.com/, and its API (https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/tree/main/docs/api).

Answer (score 3):

There's deffinitly a way to do it. 
This is how I did it;

```
curl -i -X PUT -H ‘Authorization: token 9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxe2’ -d
‘{“message”: “uploading a sample pdf”,
“content”:”bXkgbm……………………………..”
}’ https://api.github.com/repos/batman/toys/contents/sample.pdf
```

Where the content property is a base64 encoded string of characters. I used this tool to encode my pdf file. https://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html

Notice, "batman" is the owner, "toys" is  my repo, "contents" has to be there by default, and sample.pdf would the name of the file you want to upload your file as. 
In short, stick to this format: /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path
And you can run the identical step for any of these files:
*PNG (.png)
GIF (.gif)
JPEG (.jpg)
Log files (.log)
Microsoft Word (.docx), Powerpoint (.pptx), and Excel (.xlsx) documents
Text files (.txt)
PDFs (.pdf)
ZIP (.zip, .gz)*

Good luck.
Btw, I have these same details added on here: http://www.simplexanswer.com/2019/05/github-api-how-to-upload-a-file/